# Oracle JSON document select query performance tuning

Tags: oracle, oracle-nosql

**Table description**

`COLUMN          DATA_TYPE       NULLABLE    DEFAULT_VALUE
ID              VARCHAR2(16)    No 
UPDATED_DATE    TIMESTAMP(6)    Yes 
DETAILS         CLOB            Yes 
TX_STATUS       VARCHAR2(10)    Yes 
TX_USER         VARCHAR2(16)    Yes
PREMIUM          NUMBER(10,2)    Yes         JSON_VALUE("DETAILS" FORMAT JSON , '$.policy.premium' RETURNING NUMBER(10,2) NULL ON ERROR)`

*Where,*

1. DETAILS - JSON Document
2. PREMIUM - column is virtual column.

If i select virtual column with order by clause, query execution is taking too much time to run a select query.

#### The below query is taking 32.23secs. ***PREMIUM*** is the virtual column here

`select id,tx_status,updated_date,tx_user, PREMIUM from J_MARINE_CERT j order by j.UPDATED_DATE desc`

#### After removing ***PREMIUM***, it is taking 0.009secs.

`select id,tx_status,updated_date,tx_user from J_MARINE_CERT j order by j.UPDATED_DATE desc`

Even after indexing ***PREMIUM, updated_date*** it is taking same amount of time(32.23) to execute.

Comment: I think you need to explain some more details about that column.

Comment: I have updated the details about table and columns

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/json-in-oracle-database.htm#GUID-D7BCE045-EF6D-47E9-9BB2-30C01933248E__USESQLWITHJSONDATA-144609D2) suggests that you could use dot notation to directly access values inside JSON, something like this `SELECT j.DETAILS.policy.premium FROM J_MARINE_CERT j;`, but I'm not sure if that applies to you or if that is any faster than what you do now. JSON parsing is a complex operation, doing it for every row quickly adds up.

Comment: The fastest solution for any such case is to persist the calculated value into a table column and update it (e.g. through a trigger) whenever the JSON changes. If the JSON never changes, extract the value on INSERT.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: Accessing json value using dot notation like j.DETAILS.policy.premium is also very slow even for 15000records. So tried creating virtual column and indexing as well. But no improvement.

Comment: Virtual column is still a virtual column and it just parses/tranforms the data from the original column. If you need search by that field I would suggest extracting it to a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only good solution was creating a Materialized View for values from json.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_for_query_rewrite
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON STATEMENT WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS SELECT tbl.id, jt.*
   FROM jour_table tbl,
        json_table(tbl.json_document, '$' ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY
          COLUMNS (
            some_number       NUMBER       PATH '$.PONumber',
            userid          VARCHAR2(10)   PATH '$.User'
)) jt;
```

Reason for performance drop is that Oracle takes whole json in memory to select one value from it.

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-query-rewrite-use-materialized-view-json_table.html#GUID-8B0922ED-C0D1-45BD-9588-B7719BE4ECF0)